# What do algorithms `128000` and `256000` do in `sha3sum`?

Tags: hash, sha-3, checksum

I wanted to try new `sha3sum` so I installed `libdigest-sha3-perl` on Debian 10. After reading `man` page I quickly realized that:

`sha3sum --algorithm 256 test.txt`

produces similar output to `sha256sum` and that

`sha3sum --algorithm 512 test.txt`

produces similar output to `sha512sum`.

But I found two algorithms that don't really make sense to me:

```
sha3sum --algorithm 128000 test.txt
```

```
7f9c2ba4e88f827d616045507605853ed73b8093f6efbc88eb1a6eacfa66ef263cb1eea988004b93103cfb0aeefd2a686e01fa4a58e8a3639ca8a1e3f9ae57e235b8cc873c23dc62b8d260169afa2f75ab916a58d974918835d25e6a435085b2badfd6dfaac359a5efbb7bcc4b59d538df9a04302e10c8bc1cbf1a0b3a5120ea17cda7cfad765f5623474d368ccca8af0007cd9f5e4c849f167a580b14aabdefaee7eef47cb0fca9  test.txt
```

```
sha3sum --algorithm 256000 test.txt
```

```
46b9dd2b0ba88d13233b3feb743eeb243fcd52ea62b81b82b50c27646ed5762fd75dc4ddd8c0f200cb05019d67b592f6fc821c49479ab48640292eacb3b7c4be141e96616fb13957692cc7edd0b45ae3dc07223c8e92937bef84bc0eab862853349ec75546f58fb7c2775c38462c5010d846c185c15111e595522a6bcd16cf86f3d122109e3b1fdd  test.txt
```

Could you please tell me what is the point of `128000` and `256000`? `man` page does not say. It doesn't produce 128000 bit output (it's shorter) but even if it did I wonder how useful 128000/256000 bit output would be...

Thank you.

Ben

Answer (score 4):

> ... man page does not say.

It is not in the man page of sha3sum but in [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Digest::SHA3) of the module:

> Allowed values for $alg are 224, 256, 384, and 512 for the SHA3 algorithms; **or 128000 and 256000 for SHAKE128 and SHAKE256, respectively**.

Comment: Thank you Steffen. I read Keccak Wikipedia page about SHAKE### and thought that it's supposed to be weaker (and faster) then 256 / 512 bits variants. It's interesting that it has longer output...